# convert json to c# object. and name contains space or numbers only

Tags: c#, json

I need to convert json to c# object. The problem is name has space or numbers only.  see example below, I need to get stock price from Time Series (Daily) and convert to stock object.  Another Challenge is, its not an array in Time Series (Daily). how can you read each one of them? and that date will keep changing depend when you query it.

```
{
"Meta Data": {
    "1. Information": "Daily Time Series with Splits and Dividend Events",
    "2. Symbol": "IBM",
    "3. Last Refreshed": "2020-06-05",
    "4. Output Size": "Compact",
    "5. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
},
"Time Series (Daily)": {
    "2020-06-05": {
        "1. open": "133.8850",
        "2. high": "134.2300",
        "3. low": "131.7500",
        "4. close": "132.0600",
        "5. adjusted close": "132.0600",
        "6. volume": "5892718",
        "7. dividend amount": "0.0000",
        "8. split coefficient": "1.0000"
    },
    "2020-06-04": {
        "1. open": "127.7800",
        "2. high": "128.9500",
        "3. low": "127.0200",
        "4. close": "128.8900",
        "5. adjusted close": "128.8900",
        "6. volume": "3864131",
        "7. dividend amount": "0.0000",
        "8. split coefficient": "1.0000"
    },
    "2020-01-15": {
        "1. open": "136.0000",
        "2. high": "138.0550",
        "3. low": "135.7100",
        "4. close": "136.6200",
        "5. adjusted close": "133.3988",
        "6. volume": "4045591",
        "7. dividend amount": "0.0000",
        "8. split coefficient": "1.0000"
    },
    "2020-01-14": {
        "1. open": "136.2800",
        "2. high": "137.1390",
        "3. low": "135.5500",
        "4. close": "135.8200",
        "5. adjusted close": "132.6176",
        "6. volume": "3680958",
        "7. dividend amount": "0.0000",
        "8. split coefficient": "1.0000"
    }
}
```

this is my stock object.

```
 public class Stock
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Symbol { get; set; }
    public DateTime Day { get; set; }
    public decimal Open { get; set; }
    public decimal High { get; set; }
    public decimal Low { get; set; }
    public decimal Close { get; set; }
    public decimal AdjustedClose { get; set; }
    public long Volume { get; set; }
    public decimal DividendAmount { get; set; }
    public decimal SplitCoefficient { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: You need to either deserialize it to `Dictionary<string, string>` or write custom converter.

Comment: Does numbers in names the same all the time? You can use `JsonProperty` attribute for them. Also, please share your code

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the Json, extract the time series data, and then deserialize each to a `Stock` object (once you've told that which property of the Json refers to each `Stock` property)

For example:

```cs
void Main() {
    var json = GetStockJsonFromSomewhere();
    var parsed = JObject.Parse(json);
    var dailyData = parsed["Time Series (Daily)"];
    var stockdata = new List<Stock>();
    foreach (var data in dailyData.Cast<JProperty>()) {
        var stock = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Stock>(data.Value.ToString());
        stock.Day = DateTime.Parse(data.Name); 
        stockdata.Add(stock);
    }
}

public class Stock {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Symbol { get; set; }
    public DateTime Day { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("1. open")]
    public decimal Open { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("2. high")]
    public decimal High { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("3. low")]
    public decimal Low { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("4. close")]
    public decimal Close { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("5. adjusted close")]
    public decimal AdjustedClose { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("6. volume")]
    public long Volume { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("7. dividend amount")]
    public decimal DividendAmount { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("8. split coefficient")]
    public decimal SplitCoefficient { get; set; }

}
```